# React function is using old state

Tags: reactjs

I have this Page which is a list of drag-and-drop items. On drag end the list of items should be updated on the backend. The issue is `sageThemes` is, what appears to be, an old state from the first `handleMoveItem` call. Meaning the theme only gets moved up/down 1 as far as the backend is concerned but the frontend appears correct.

```
import { SideBarNav } from "@/Components/SideBarNav";
import SidebarLayout from "@/Layouts/SideBarLayout";
import { Head } from "@inertiajs/react";
import { navigation } from "@/StandardNavigationList";
import { useState } from "react";
import { SageTheme, castSageTheme } from "@/types/models/SageTheme";
import axios from "axios";
import DragDropItem from "@/Components/DragandDropItem"

interface Props {
    sage_themes: SageTheme[];
}

export interface Item {
    sequence: number;
    text: string;
    checked: string;
}

export default function SageThemesPage(props: Props) {
    const [sageThemes, setSageThemes] = useState(props.sage_themes.map((sageTheme) => castSageTheme(sageTheme)));

    function handleMoveItem(dragIndex: number, hoverIndex: number) {
        setSageThemes(prevState => {
            const dragItem = prevState[dragIndex];
            console.log("dragIndex " + dragIndex);
            const hoverItem = prevState[hoverIndex];
            console.log("hoverIndex " + hoverIndex);
            prevState[dragIndex] = hoverItem;
            prevState[hoverIndex] = dragItem;
            return [...prevState]
        });
    };

    function updateAllThemes() {
        axios.put('/3rdparty/sage/themes/updateAll', {
            sageThemes
        });
    }

    function sageThemeItem(sageTheme: SageTheme, index: number) {


        return (
            <DragDropItem
                id={sageTheme.k_sage_theme_id}
                index={index}
                key={index}
                divideX={true}
                moveItem={handleMoveItem}
                onDragEnd={updateAllThemes}
            />
        );
    }

    return (
        <SidebarLayout
            nav={<SideBarNav navigation={navigation}></SideBarNav>}
            header={<Head title="Dashboard" />}
        >
            {sageThemes.map(
                (sageTheme, index) => {
                    return sageThemeItem(sageTheme, index)
                }
            )}
        </SidebarLayout>
    );
}
```

What's the solution to updating the backend with the current state?

Comment: You should clone the state first, make modifications to the cloned state, and finally return the cloned state. You are mutating the incoming `prevState` object. Don't do that. Also, take a look at [`structuredClone`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/structuredClone) for cloning complex objects.